# How to record one vote per user php

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am trying to write a php script that records one vote increment per user. Voters a are presented with a list of prospective candidates then clicks once on their name. 
Now on attempt of a second time i hope to get a notification allowing this action. Please help.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['vote']))
{
    $sql3='INSERT INTO sessions (memberID, postid, email, voted) VALUES ("","", "", 1;)';

    $result3 =   mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
}
//  $count  =   mysqli_num_rows($result2);
$candidate_name = null;
$vote = $_POST['vote'];
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbCandidates SET candidate_votes=candidate_votes+1 WHERE  position_id='$vote'");

// $count  =   mysqli_num_rows($result2);

if ( $count<1) {
    //$sql3='INSERT INTO sessions (memberID, postid, voted) VALUES ("", memberbers.memberID,"1")';
    //$result = mysqlI_query("select id from Users where username ='".$_SESSION['email']."'");
    //$result =   mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
    // $count  =   mysqli_num_rows($result2); 
} else {
     echo"You have voted already"; 
}
```

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You state what you want to happen, but your attached code does not show a coherent effort to achieve what you want - it appears to me like you got new requirement, and immediately without working on it just dumped existing code into StackOverflow question box. So. What have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Put a "unique" flag on your memberID column in your SQL table. In that case when you try to insert a new row with the same memberID, it will not work.

Then catch the SQL write fail, and display a message if it gets to it.